# Dovecot default config?

Tags: 13.04, dovecot

I have neglected to make a backup of the file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf

Could somebody who has a fresh install or a working config file post it? I tweaked a setting and now i cannot figure out the problem.

Here is a copy of my current configuration file. I formatted it in .txt so that it would allow me to upload it. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93765018/10-master.conf.txt

Answer (score 0):

Run `doveconf -d` which will show you the default values for settings.

Or run `doveconf -n` which will print you the settings which are currently set to some non-default value.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, doveconf -n doesn't work because that 10-master.conf file is incorrectly formatted. This is why I am requesting a copy.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately I do not have acces to any dovecot right now so I cannot help more. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: Thank again. I figured out that it has something to do with smtp auth because once i comment it out everything starts working (No correctly but it runs)